# How to format the date field in WSO2 EI Rest API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to format the Date field from a WSo2 EI REST API 
currently i am getting the response in the below format.

```
{
    "Members": {
        "member": [
            {
                "First_Name": "FLORENCE       ",
                "Effective_Date": "2019-05-01-07:00"
}]}}
```

But I want the response to be like

```
                "Effective_Date": "2019-05-01"
```

I tried with "Effective_Date":"$effective_date(type:dateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD')"

```
<config id="DataSource"> 
    <property name="jndi_resource_name">jdbc/datasourcename</property>
</config> 
<query id="get_new_touchMembers" useConfig="DataSource"> 
    <sql>EXECUTE databasename..SP_NAME</sql> 
    <result outputType="json"> {
     "Members":{ "member":[ { "S.NO":"$s.NO", "ID":"$id", "DOB":"$dob", "Effective_Date":"$effective_date", "Term_Date":"$term_date", "Plan_Description":"$plan_description" } ] } } </result> 
</query>
```

Comment: Please share the sourcecode of your rest API.  Or at least the sourcecode where you transform/build the response message.

Comment: <config id="DataSource">
<property name="jndi_resource_name">jdbc/datasourcename</property>
</config>
<query id="get_new_touchMembers" useConfig="DataSource">
<sql>EXECUTE databasename..SP_NAME</sql>
<result outputType="json">
{  
"Members":{  
"member":[  
{  
"S.NO":"$s.NO",
"ID":"$id",
"DOB":"$dob",
"Effective_Date":"$effective_date",
"Term_Date":"$term_date",
"Plan_Description":"$plan_description"
}
]
}
}
</result>
</query>

Comment: Seems you are trying to get some data from a Datasource. Why don't you alter your query to get the date from the required format? I think that will be the easiest option here.

Comment: Yes, the date is coming in yyyy-mm-dd but when the query is implemented in DSS the response is adding the offset value along with the date.

Comment: Please show me the query you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try this property as it works for me!

```html
<property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyy-MM-dd')" name="effective_date" scope="default"/>
```